# Same SVG is rendered when trying to import two different SVG's with different src locations

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I am trying to import another SVG, using the `<object>` tag, however, even with two different src properties, the same SVG is loading. How is this possible? What's wrong?

Link to repo: https://github.com/ColinTS/readable/tree/master/app/src
Imports are found in `App.js` and in `components/PostCard.js`

SVG 1 (the one being rendered twice):

```
<div className="App-header">
  <img src="./assets/logo.svg" className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
</div>
```

SVG 2:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="../assets/uparrow.svg">
</object>
```

Comment: img tags aren't closed with /> otherwise it's hard to say. We'd need a [mcve]

Comment: @RobertLongson - OK, the image is rendering though. How would you close it - looks like you can't close with </img>. I updated my question and linked my repo with where the files are being imported: https://github.com/ColinTS/readable/tree/master/app/src

Comment: void tags are closed with >

Comment: What does the browser's DOM look like?

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. It was a React.js thing. For some reason, I had to import the SVG as a variable with the pathname instead of hard coding the pathname in as the prop value. No idea why, haha, just one of those things I am going to accept and move on :)